# find different elements of two lists

Tags: python

I have two lists, l1 and l2 and I want to compare the lists l1 and l2. Then I want to 
 find list elements that are different from each other. Lists are as follows:

```
l1= [('A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'), ('F', '2', '4', '2.2', '2.7', '3'), ('G', '5', '2.1', '3.4', '1.5', '2'),('H', 'L', 'L', 'D', 'C', 'B')]

l2= [('A', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6'),('H', 'L', 'L', 'D', 'C', 'B')]
```

the output I want is:

```
l3=[('F', '2', '4', '2.2', '2.7', '3'), ('G', '5', '2.1', '3.4', '1.5', '2')]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: What did you try? Please include your attempt(s). Also, the question is not clear. Why is the 'A' element in the output if it is on both lists?

Comment: Excuse me. I organized the question. I want to compare lists l1 and l2 then I want to assign the different elements of lists to variable l3 @DyZ

Answer (score 1):

Assuming order doesn't matter, you can use `set(l1) ^ set(l2)`.

Comment: I tried it but I got an error like this: TypeError: unhashable type: 'list' @AlexHall

Comment: The data in the format you gave in the question does not do that. Sounds like you have a list of lists rather than a list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

this is the code that does what you need:

```
output_list = []
if len(l1) < len(l2):
    shortest_list = l1
    other_list = l2
else:
    shortest_list = l2
    other_list = l1
for tup in other_list:
    if tup not in shortest_list:
        output_list.append(tup)
print output_list
```

output list is l3.

i hope it helps you,

dor